# need gcc in rhel 7 and have no repositories

Tags: gcc, rhel

I'm working on a rhel 7 that does not have the repos configured, I need to compile c code and I hace no gcc.

I've tried to download individual rpm but there are a lot of dependencies, what repo can be installed on the system?, I tried with rpmforge but but still can't install gcc.

Have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try Developer Toolset which includes GCC, etc. from the Software Collections channel?  info here: https://access.redhat.com/products/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/Developer/#dev-page=6